# disable selected value in md-select

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, md-select

I have a table which has **md-select** in all the rows which come dynamically from ng-repeat. how to restrict the selected value from **md-options** in one row to not to get visible in other rows.. here is the code I used for **md-select**

```
<tbody>
<tr ng-repeat="receiver in receivers">
    <td>
        <md-select ng-model="receiver.product">
            <md-option ng-repeat="product in products" value="{{product}}">
                {{product.name}}
            </md-option>
        </md-select>
    </td>
</tr>
```

here is my Plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/1gM6GKPWRou7dLYDDRgi?p=preview
if i select product1 in first row and click on **+** to add new row , then product1 should be disabled.

I have tried these answers but no luck.
https://jsfiddle.net/rdkqw5gt/10/ & http://plnkr.co/edit/E0yu9XAxqjxpwArBfDbK?p=preview

they have used **ng-options** how to achieve this in md-options??
thanks in advance

Comment: provide a plunker with md-select

Comment: @Sajeetharan i have added plunker in my question.. here again http://plnkr.co/edit/1gM6GKPWRou7dLYDDRgi?p=preview

Comment: any answers for this question?